# Serve pre-made gzip files

Tags: node.js, webpack, gzip

I use compression-webpack-plugin to make gzip files durring my bundle process, so when bundling is done I have files like this in my dist folder.

```
bundle.eefaef91f71795847e74.js
bundle.eefaef91f71795847e74.js.gz
vendor.jduu4f4lj71759dj7e74.js
vendor.jduu4f4lj71759dj7e74.js.gz
stylesLocal.b7ac53d721aca93e4e65099cf74dc90f.css
stylesLocal.b7ac53d721aca93e4e65099cf74dc90f.css.gz
```

Inside server I use [express-static-gzip](https://github.com/tkoenig89/express-static-gzip) to serve my gzip files. Why isn't this working. My page doesnt even wanna load? If I put **Express.static** instead of **expressStaticGzip** it works normally.

```
import Express from 'express'
import path from 'path'
import conf from './conf'
import appRenderer from './appRenderer'
import webpackUtils from './webpackUtils'
var expressStaticGzip = require('express-static-gzip')

const APP_PORT: number = conf.APP_PORT
const PORT: any = process.env.PORT || APP_PORT

const app: Express = new Express()

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(expressStaticGzip(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'dist')))

/* check with the server before using the cached resource */
app.use((req: Object, res: Object, next: () => void): void => {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
  return next()
})

/* Use server side rendering for first load */
app.use(appRenderer)

/* Use CommonChunks and long term caching */
app.use(webpackUtils)

// Routes
app.get('*', (req: Object, res: Object) => {
  res.render('index', {app: req.body})
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`
  Express server is up on port ${PORT}
  Production environment
  `)
})
```

And I refernce them in my index.ejs file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <title>D</title>

      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="stylesLocal.b7ac53d721aca93e4e65099cf74dc90f.css">
</head>

  <body>

      <div id="app"><%- app %></div>
      <script src="vendor.jduu4f4lj71759dj7e74.js"></script>
      <script src="bundle.eefaef91f71795847e74.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [readme of express-static-gzip](https://github.com/tkoenig89/express-static-gzip#usage), the syntax is slightly different from `express.static`.

Instead of

```
app.use(expressStaticGzip(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'dist')))
```

try

```
app.use('/', expressStaticGzip(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'dist')))
```